# A Question about Correlation

Tags: probability, statistics

Please consider the following problem and my answer. I would like somebody to check it.
Thank You
Bob

Problem:

Suppose that $x$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on the interval $(0,6)$ and $y = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{2}$. What is the correlation between $x$ and $y$?

Answer:

First observe that $u_x = E(x)  = 3$ and $u_y = E(y) = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 3 = E(x)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(x^2) &=& \int_0^6 \frac{x^2}{6} \,\,\, dx  = \frac{x^3}{18} \Big|_0^6  = \frac{6^3}{18}\\
E(x^2) &=& \frac{6(36)}{{18}} = \frac{36}{3} = 12 \\
\sigma_x^2 &=& E(x^2) - (E(x))^2 = 12 - 3^2 = 3 \\
\sigma_x &=& \sqrt{3} \\
E(y^2) &=& E( (\frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{2} ) ^2 )  = E( \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{9}{4} )\\
E(y^2) &=& \frac{1}{4}E( x^2 ) + \frac{3}{2}E(x) + \frac{9}{4} \\
E(y^2) &=&\frac{1}{4}(12) + \frac{3}{2}(3)  + \frac{9}{4} = \frac{12}{4} + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{4} \\
E(y^2) &=&  \frac{ 12 + 18 + 9}{4} = \frac{39}{4} \\
\sigma_y^2 &=& E(y^2) - (E(y))^2 = \frac{39}{4} - 3^2 \\
\sigma_y^2 &=& \frac{39-36}{4} = \frac{3}{4} \\
\sigma_y &=& \frac{ \sqrt{3} } { 2 } \\
cov(x,y) &=& E((x - u_x)(y - u_y)) = E(xy) - u_x u_y = E(xy) - 3(3) = E(xy) - 9 \\
E(xy) &=& E(x(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{3}{2})) = \frac{1}{2} E(x^2 + 3x)  = \frac{1}{2} ( 12 + 3(3) )\\
E(xy) &=& \frac{21}{2} \\
cov(x,y) &=& \frac{21}{2} - 9 = \frac{21-18}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \\
\rho_{xy} &=& \frac{cov(x,y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} = \frac{ \frac{3}{2} } { \sqrt{3} ( 2\sqrt{3} ) } \\
\rho_{xy} &=& \frac{ \frac{3}{2} } { \sqrt{3} ( \frac{ \sqrt{3}} {2} ) } = \frac{ \frac{3}{2} }{ \frac{3}{2 } }  \\
\rho_{xy} &=& 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Since $y$ is a linear function of $x$ and $\frac12 >0$, the correlation should be $1$

Comment: I would have expected $\sigma^2_x =3$, $\sigma^2_y =\frac34$ and $cov(x,y)=\frac32$

Comment: @Henry You wrote that the correlation should be $1$. I do not understand why. I suspect there is a theorem you know that enables you to draw that conclusion. If so, what is it?

Comment: Bob: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence and *"The Pearson correlation is +1 in the case of a perfect direct (increasing) linear relationship"*

Comment: I agree with Henry, your $\sigma_y^2$ is wrong. In general if $y = ax + b$ then $\text{var}(ax+b) = a^2 \text{var}(x)$. So your $\sigma_y^2$ should be $3/4$. Your error is that you wrote $x/2 + 3$ instead of $x/2 + 3/2$ in your expression for $E(y^2)$.

Comment: P.S. The formula for the variance of a uniform random variable on an interval $(a,b)$ is easy enough and useful enough to justify committing to memory: it's simply $(b-a)^2 / 12$.

Comment: By the way, the reason the correlation coefficient is $\pm 1$ when one random variable is a linear function of the other is because this is precisely the condition for equality in the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality). For some reason, the Wikipedia page cited by @Henry doesn't mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(X) = 3$
$E(Y) = 3$

$E(X^2) = \int_0^6  x^2f_X(x) = \int_0^6 \frac{x^2}{6} = 12$

$E(XY) = E(\frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{3X}{2})  = E(\frac{X^2}{2})+ E(\frac{3X}{2}) =  6+ 4.5=10.5$

$COV(X,Y) =E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = 10.5-9 = 1.5$

Next the variance:

$VAR(X)=3 => VAR(Y)=\frac{3}{4}$

$Corr(X,Y) = \frac{1.5}{\sqrt {3*3/4}}=1$

The point of this answer, the math of the solution gets a bit complicated to my taste.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, given that $Y$ is a linear function of $X$ (say, in general: $Y=aX+b$) 
$$
E[Y] = E [ aX+b] = aE[ X]+b\\
Var[Y]=a^2 Var[X]
$$ 
and

$$
E[X Y] = E [ E [ X Y | X] = E[ X E [ Y \mid X] = E[X \left( aX+b\right)]
=aE[X^2]+b E[X]$$

$$Cov[X,Y]=E[XY]- E[X] E [Y]=aE[X^2]+b E[X]-aE^2[X]-bE[X]=aVar[X]$$

$$\rho_{X,Y}=\frac{a Var[X]}{\sqrt{a^2 Var^2[X]}}=\frac{a}{|a|}=sign(a)$$